# Where do I find Azure.Service Powershell Module?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to use some commands from PowerShell workflow from runbooks in Azure automation account. One of the command is [Get-AzureWebsiteJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/get-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) which uses Azure.Service PowerShell module. This module is not present in the PowerShell module gallery of the automation account. I didn't find it in [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) as well.

Am I missing anything trivial here? Either I need a way to import that module in automation account or need to be able to download as a zip so that I can upload it.

Comment: I believe the module you're looking for is `Azure` (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.3.1).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: @GauravMantri You are back to SO.  Since when?? We missed you. Thanks I'll check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the cmdlet `Get-AzureWebsiteJob` is in [Azure module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.3.0).

In the [Azure module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.3.0) page -> `Package Details` section, you can find the cmdlet `Get-AzureWebsiteJob` is included. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

To use it in runbook, you just need import that module in automation account, or you can directly deploy that module to azure automation from [Azure module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.3.0) like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I imported the module from 'module gallery' of automation account. I was searching for Azure.service module because Azure module was present in 'modules' of azure automation though it didn't work. After reading the comments on the post, I realized that import of azure module had failed. Deleting it and importing it worked after all the depended modules were updated.